# JavaScript slideshow that changes slides every 3 seconds and starts on a random image

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, setinterval

```
var Image = new Array("slideshow01.jpg", "slideshow2.jpg",  "slideshow3.jpg")                                        

    var Image_Number = 0;
    var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;

    setInterval(“change_image(1)”, 3000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="slideshow01.jpg" name="slideshow"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="return change_image(-1)"/>
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="change_image(1)"/>
</body>
```

Comment: So what does it not do/do wrong? You haven't even told us what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry about that just signed up.  The slides run you click the "next" and "previous" button, but it doesn't change images after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the setInterval as so:

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    changeImage(1);
}, 3000);
```

Because you are just passing it as a string and not invoking it as a function.

Slideshow tutorial in pure javascript.

[Better simple slideshow](http://themarklee.com/2014/10/05/better-simple-slideshow/)

Comment: I tried it and my html stays on the same image and the buttons don't allow me to move to the next slide.

Comment: i just ran it again and it now works, thank you.

Comment: hey could you help me in starting my slideshow with a random slide

Comment: I could reference you to some good slideshow code, it's vanilla javascript. http://themarklee.com/2014/10/05/better-simple-slideshow/